# Олимпиадная задачка на python

Tags: python

Мой код возвращает очень близкие к ответам значения, но где-то есть прокол, не могу его найти.

```
def distances_sum(length: int, arr: list[int]) -> int:
    l = []
    res = 0
    for i in range(length - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, length):
            if j == length - 1:
                l.append(arr[:i] + sorted(arr[i:]))
            else:
                l.append(arr[:i] + sorted(arr[i:j]) + arr[j:])
    for i in arr[:-1]:
        for j in arr[arr.index(i) + 1:]:
            res += max(abs(lst.index(i) - lst.index(j)) for lst in l)
    return res
```

> **Условие**
>
> *Задан массив [p1, p2, . . . , pn], содержащий n различных целых чисел от 1 до n. Можно выбрать один любой отрезок массива с l-й по r-ю
> позицию включительно (1 ⩽ l ⩽ r ⩽ n), то есть [pl , pl+1, . . . , pr],
> и отсортировать элементы массива на этом отрезке в порядке
> возрастания. Например, если n = 5, изначально числа стояли в порядке
> [5, 2, 4, 1, 3], и был выбран отрезок с l = 2 и r = 4, то после
> сортировки числа в массиве будут стоять в порядке [5, 1, 2, 4, 3].
> Расстояние между числами в массиве равно разности номеров позиций, на
> которых они стоят. Обозначим d(a, b) наибольшее возможное расстояние,
> на котором могут оказаться числа a и b после сортировки чисел на одном
> отрезке. Например, в приведенном выше массиве d(1, 3) = 4: чтобы числа
> 1 и 3 оказались на расстоянии 4, можно выбрать отрезок с l = 1 и r =
> 4. Тогда массив изменится следующим образом [5, 2, 4, 1, 3] → [1, 2, 4, 5, 3]. Выбранный отрезок подчеркнут. Требуется вычислить сумму
> значений d(a, b) по всем парам чисел a и b (1 ⩽ a < b ⩽ n). Например,
> если n = 5, то необходимо вычислить сумму d(1, 2) + d(1, 3) + d(1, 4)
>
> - d(1, 5) + d(2, 3) + d(2, 4) + d(2, 5) + d(3, 4) + d(3, 5) + d(4, 5).*
>
> **Формат входных данных**
>
> *В первой строке дано одно целое число n — количество элементов массива (2 ⩽ n ⩽ 3 000). Во второй строке даны n различных целых чисел
> p1, p2, . . . , pn — элементы массива (1 ⩽ pi ⩽ n).*
>
> **Формат выходных данных**
>
> *Выведите одно целое число — ответ на задачу.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вывести подмассивы l в цикле, то можно заметить, что выводится всего 10 вариантов для массива-примера, и только один начинается с единицы. Это означает, что перебраны не все пары начала и конца. Вот так будут все 15:

```
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(i+1, length+1):
        if j == length:
            l.append(arr[:i] + sorted(arr[i:]))
        else:
            l.append(arr[:i] + sorted(arr[i:j]) + arr[j:])
        print(i,j-1, l[-1])   #контроль
```

Кроме того, кажется разумным сделать последний цикл попроще.

```
for i in range(1, length):
    for j in range(i+1, length+1):
```

P.S. сложность решения `O(n^3*log(n))` выглядит великоватой, ну да вопрос был не в этом.